# Pandas: preferred idioms for boolean/predicate searches

Tags: python, pandas

I have two questions and they are both in **bold** in the post below.

Consider this `DataFrame`:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df_1 = DataFrame ({
        "x" : ["a - {}".format(i) for i in range(2)] + 
              ["b - {}".format(i) for i in range(2)] ,
        "y" : range(4)
    })
df_1
```

[image]

Suppose I wanted all rows where the `x` value started with the letter "a".

**Is the following the preferred idiom for such a search?**

```
df_1[df_1["x"].apply(lambda val : val.startswith("a"))]
```

[image]

One thing I find in Pandas is that once meaningful data becomes a `DataFrame` index, it is harder to do things with it, especially query it. Suppose we now have:

```
df_2 = df_1.set_index(["x"], drop=True)
df_2
```

[image]

I find that to do the same search, more work is involved if I am searching the index.

**Is the following the preferred idiom for such a search?**

```
df_2.iloc[[i for i,val in enumerate(df_2.index.tolist()) if val.startswith("a")], :]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, I would use the vectorized `.str.startswith(...)` method.  It's not necessarily that much more performant, just cleaner.  See the [working with text documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) for more.

```
In [22]: df_1[df_1["x"].str.startswith("a")]
Out[22]: 
       x  y
0  a - 0  0
1  a - 1  1

In [23]: df_2[df_2.index.str.startswith('a')]
Out[23]: 
       y
x       
a - 0  0
a - 1  1
```

Comment: I was not aware of these `str` methods.  This opens up a whole new world. Thx!